# Retrieve image in RSS feed description with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, text, rss

```
<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <description/>
        <title>Example</title>
        <link>http://example.com/</link>
        <item>
            <title>
              My Post Title
            </title>
            <description>
                <div class="thumbnail"><a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/192384.jpg"/> </a></div> <p class="intro"><span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span> <!-- more --> <span> Duis end </h3> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/wq8fu.png"/><div class="credit"> Clas Henrik </div> </span></p>
            </description>
         </item>
     </channel>
</rss>
```

How do I retrieve the first image in the RSS `<description>`, the one wrapped in `<div class="thumbnail">`?  
 I am using jQuery and I've managed to read the whole description block with this code:

```
var rssurl = 'http://example.com/rss';
$.get(rssurl, function(data) {
    var $xml = $(data);
    var vari = 0;
    $xml.find("item").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
          item = {
            description: $this.find("description").text()
          }

    });
});
```

But all I want is the image. Since it's in text now I can't just select it with `$('.thumbnail > a > img);`

...
**Edit:** Reformatted my question

Answer (score 0):

Managed to retrieve the first image through this:
`description: $this.find("description").text().substring(0, 200).match("<img src(.*)/>")`